# Nexus 7 incompatible because of manifest settings

Tags: android, nexus-7

my app doesn't show up on the Nexus 7.
the play store console shows for the Nexus 7 in the devices list:

```
Unsupported devices due to your manifest settings:

Nexus 7(grouper)"
```

my manifest looks like this:

```
...

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14">
</uses-sdk>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>

...
```

I do not require a camera which seems to be the case for the usual incompatibility issues. 
I am not using the `supports-screens` entry ( I want to exclude all small screen devices, as well as ldpi normal devices and this is not possible using the supports-screens entry AFAIK).

any idea what could be thr problem?

one interesting detail might be that the nexus 7 reports having DENSITY_TV (213dpi). However, "tv" is not a possible value for the android:screenDensity tag.

EDIT:
developer console reports the following required permissions:

```
Permissions: 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
com.android.vending.BILLING, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Features: 
android.hardware.screen.landscape, 
android.hardware.touchscreen, 
android.hardware.wifi
```

Comment: i've noticed that the nexus 7 works just fine using hdpi stuff.

Comment: Go into the apk tab in the developer console, and click more... Then copy paste the required permissions and features listed there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed true, you cannot add `"tvdpi"` to the manifest. There is a workaround though, if you enter `"213"` instead, which as you have pointed out is the `dpi` value of the density, eclipse will be happy with it and you will also have your application showing up on nexus 7 devices.

Answer (score 4):

Reading your permissions list, the `READ_PHONE_STATE` there might be causing Google Play to imply that your app requires `android.hardware.telephony` feature which is not available on Nexus 7.

Try adding this to your manifest to resolve this issue:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

You can read more about ["Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements" here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Comment: there are many other tablets ( eg. the acer iconia a500 or the asus transormer tabs ) withouth mobile network that are compatible with the app; so I don't think that should be the reason. but if the biddulph.r's tip won't work I'll try that...

Answer (score 3):

Once, I uploaded my app. It was not available to nexus 7 either. In my case it was caused because I had in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I had the above line because I was giving the possibility to call a telephone number with an Intent in one application screen. This feature was a minor one and was not crucial for the application at all. That it is to say I wanted the application to run in devices without telephone capabilities.

I found this post [Five Steps to Futre Hardware Hapinness](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/five-steps-to-future-hardware-happiness.html) in the Android Developer Blog which explains exactly the issue.

Adding the next line to the manifest file, generating a new APK, and uploading it to the Play Store made my app compatible to another group of devices including the nexus 7.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```